# Exceção na leitura do arquivo XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

Há semanas tento resolver esse erro na leitura do XML. Estou criando um aplicativo para Windows Phone 8 em C#. No momento em que clico em um assunto e assim apresentar a pagina com um listBox.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was                                  not handled in user code

O erro ocorre nessa linha de código:

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

[image]

Comment: É melhor colar o código do que uma captura de tela. Você pode [edit] a pergunta para incluir mais detalhes. Falta colocar a tag da linguagem também, não sei qual é...

Comment: Qual o valor de `xml`? Essa variável é nula?

Comment: O xml Carlos, irá ler o aquivo .xml, depois criará um parser e gerar uma lista com os conteúdos no arquivo.

Comment: O erro ocorre na linha Xdocument.Parse(xml)?

Answer (score 1):

Estou postando um exemplo de como ler um xml do disco e desserializa-lo para uma classe.
Desta forma você não precisa ficar pegando cada item manualmente. 
Isso funciona em um projeto antigo que tenho aqui.
Vamos lá para as explicações de utilização.

**Esse é o modelo do meu exemplo de xml.**

```
<Pages> 
  <Page>
    <Name>Page 1</Name>
    <Url>http://www.google.com</Url>
    <XPathExpression></XPathExpression>
  </Page>
  <Page>    
    <Name>Page 2</Name>
    <Url></Url>
    <XPathExpression></XPathExpression>
  </Page>  
</Pages>
```

**Está é uma classe que utilizo para carregar o xml, serializa-lo e desserializa-lo.**

```
public class UtilXML
    {
        //Private fields        

        //Public fields 
        public XmlDocument XmlDocument { get; set; }

        public UtilXML() { }

        public void LoadXMLByPath(string FilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDocument.Load(FilePath);               
            }
            catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
            {
                throw new System.Xml.XmlException(e.Message);

            }
        }

        public void SerializeToXml<T>(T obj, string FileName)
        {
            XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            FileStream FileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Create);
            XmlSerializer.Serialize(FileStream, obj);
            FileStream.Close();
        }

        public T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string StringXML)
        {
            T Result;
            XmlSerializer XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (TextReader TextReader = new StringReader(StringXML))
            {
                Result = (T)XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader);
            }
            return Result;
        }
    }

Essas são as classes que representam meu xml. Repare nos atributos que decoram essa classe. Eles tem os mesmos nomes dos elementos do xml.

[XmlRoot("Pages")]
    public sealed class Pages
    {
        [XmlElement("Page")]
        public List<Page> Items { get; set; }

        public Pages() 
        {
            Items = new List<Page>(); 
        }
    }
    public sealed class Page
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Url")]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("XPathExpression")]
        public string XPathExpression { get; set; }
    }
```

**Exemplo de utilização:**

**Carregar xml**

```
UtilXML.LoadXMLByPath(@"C:\temp\Pages.xml");
```

**Desserializar para a classe Pages.**

```
Pages = this.UtilXML.DeserializeFromXml<Pages>(this.UtilXML.XmlDocument.InnerXml);
```

Comment: Obrigado cara. Consegui resolver !!!

Answer (score 1):

Esperando que seja relevante, caso o problema esteja relacionado a um valor vazio há uma alternativa. Criar um método de extensão.

Crie uma classe com métodos como esse

```
public static class MetodosExtensao
{
    public static string ElementValueOrEmpty(this XElement element)
    {
        if (element != null)
            return element.Value;

        return "";
    }
}
```

Nesse caso é a leitura de uma String, eu faço um para cada tipo de item.

Na classe que irá efetuar a leitura de xml adicione a classe como os métodos de extensão

```
using MetodosExtensao;
```

e a leitura do XML será conforme abaixo:

```
XDocument r; //aqui irá receber o xml     
IList<Classe> Lista = (from retorno in r.Descendants("Data").Elements("values")
                                                 select new Classe
                                                 {
                                                     nome = retornoBusca.Element("nome").ElementValueOrEmpty()
                                                 }).ToList();
```

É isso. Esse é o procedimento que uso, sou iniciante então desculpe algum erro na resposta ou no código.

Answer (score 0):

É quase certo que a variável xml está nula por algum motivo. Considere validar o valor da mesma antes de usá-la para instanciar o objeto XDocument.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas creio que mesmo assim não dê... Veja só:

        // le o arquivo XML
           //   String xml =        Utils.readFile("Resources\\xml\\eventos_" + tipo + ".xml"); //
Ele está recebendo algo, nesse caso o caminho do arquivo

Comment: O problema é que essa função é personalizada, faz parte do seu código. Pode estar acontecendo algum comportamento indesejado dentro dela.